# Possible to use the default Controller.php in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

I added a method to the default `app/Http/Controllers/Controller` class, and tried to invoke it from my `routes/web.php` file, but get this error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target [Illuminate\Routing\Controller] is not instantiable.
```

Most/all (?) tutorials seem to talk about creating a new controller -- I don't actually want a new controller -- the existing controller seems good enough -- don't want an extra class just to hold a single function.

Can I just use the existing controller?

My route in routes/web.php is:

```
Route::get('/addarticle', [Controller::class, 'add_article']);
```

My controller function:

```
function add_article( Request $request ){
    return "hello, from /addarticle controller";
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *does* seem possible to use the default Controller.php class/file -- I was just not importing it into my web.php correctly:

```
  4 //use Illuminate\Routing\Controller; // wrong
  5 
  6 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; // correct
```

Thanks!

Comment: keep in mind, any other controllers extend this controller.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can use Controller class but you will have to import correct Controller class